# Is this a necessary and sufficient condition of a continuous linear functional to be injective?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Is it true that a continuous linear functional $f$ is injective if and only if there exist a constant $M\gt 0$, and for any given $x \in (X,||\cdot||)$,  such that $|f(x)|\ge M||x||$?

I know it is obviously from the right hand side we can get the left hand side.

But I want to know is the opposite direction still true？

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed some condition. I edit it now.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the condintion that $f$ is a linear function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Take the space $\mathcal{l}^1(\mathbb{R})$, the space of the absolutely summable sequences, with the norm $\| u\|_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |u_n|$

Now define the operator $T: l^1 \to l^1$ by

$T(u)_k = \frac{u_k}{k+1}$

It's injective, but there is no $M$ such that $\forall u \in l^1, \|T(u)\|_1 \geq M\|u\|_1$. Indeed, let's define $u^{(n)}$ by $u^{(n)}_k = 1$ if $k=n$, $0$ if $k\neq n$.

Then we have $\| u^{(n)}\|_1 = 1$, but $\| T(u^{(n)}) \|_1 = \frac{1}{n+1}$

So if there was such an $M$, it would need to be lower or equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n$. ie. equal to $0$

Comment: is it true for $T:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Goodboy : Yes, in this case it's true... But if $X$ is not of dimension 1 (over $\mathbb{C}$), there is no injective linear operator $T: X\to \mathbb{C}$, so it's kinda a moot point.  It's also true for linear operator between finite dimensionnal vector spaces

Answer (score 0):

My other answer show that it's not true in the general case. But what if $X$ is finite dimensional?

In this case, it's true. A possible argument :

Suppose there is no such $M$. Then there exist a sequence $(x_n) \in X$ with $\|x_n\| = 1$ such that $\| f(x_n) \| \to 0$

But, as $X$ is finite dimensional, the unit sphere of $X$ is compact, so we can extract a subsequence $x_{\sigma(n)}$ that converge in $X$ toward $x$.

And then $f(x) = f( \lim x_{\sigma(n)} ) = \lim f(x_{\sigma(n)}) = 0$ (by continuity of $f$)

But $f$ is injective, so $x=0$

But a sequence of elements with norm 1 cannot converge to zero : absurd